# pandas: first steps with merge, join, and concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the one below, with 3 columns and 12 rows. The 12 rows are 4 repeated classes (for three time). I know that I have never values for 1A, 1D, 2B and 2D cells, and that I have always cell values for 1B, 1C, 2A and 2C cells.

[image]

I would like to transform it in something like the one you see below, in wich I combine column and row names to extract all the cells that I know will have always data inside.
In this way I will avoid unnecessary repetition or unnecessary empty cells.

[image]

I have tried to read the manual http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html, but I have some difficult to take the right way. Some advice for me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#get index to MultiIndex in column
df = df.set_index(['class','date']).unstack(level=0)
#remove columns with all NaN, sort index
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all').sort_index(ascending=False)
#reset MultiIndex in columns, cast int to str in first level (1,2 values)
df.columns = [''.join((str(col[0]),col[1])) for col in df.columns]
#index to column
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
#reorder columns
df = df[df.columns[1:].union(df.columns[:1])]
print (df)
         1B        1C        2A            2C        date
0  1.462543  4.920529  4.496126  3.362060e+08  2016-10-31
1  3.931170  3.439862  2.453640  1.488948e+00  2016-10-30
2  3.550311  3.504713  3.224958  1.804881e+00  2016-10-29
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much, you are very kind.

I have this error:
```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-791cb920d06d> in <module>()
      8 #    print col
      9 
---> 10 df.columns = [''.join(col) for col in df.columns]
     11 '''
     12 #index to column

TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, int found
```

Comment: You need cast `int` to `str` - use `df.columns = [''.join((str(col[0]),col[1])) for col in df.columns]`

Comment: Thank you again, but it seems not work. I have 3 rows x 25 columns and not 3 rows x 5 columns. I have inserted all in this gist https://gist.github.com/aborruso/8eb51579335cd94d44c033bea2b27748

Comment: You need `df = df.set_index(['class','date']).unstack(level=0)` - set index with both columns. before I think column `class` is index.

Comment: It works!!! https://gist.github.com/aborruso/8eb51579335cd94d44c033bea2b27748

Thank you very much, I'm really astonished